# How to only search data only in one div area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(function(){
    var roles = ["Admin", "User", "Dealer", "Agent", "Buyer", "Guest", "User", "Dealer", "Agent"];

    $.each(roles, function(){
      $(".role_wrapper_2").append("<div class='roles_approval'><span>" + this + "</span></div>");
    });
  });

  $(".role-search-approval").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
      $(".roles_approval").each(function() {
          if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1) {
              $(this).show();
          } else {
              $(this).hide();    
          }
      });
  });


  $(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.role_wrapper_2 .roles_approval', function(){
      var role= $(this)
      $('.role_wrapper_1').append(role);
      $(this).find("img").attr('src', 'images/02_button_minus.png');
    });
  });

  $(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.role_wrapper_1 .roles_approval', function(){
      var role = $(this)
      $('.role_wrapper_2').append(role);
      $(this).find("img").attr('src', 'images/02_button_add.png');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.role_wrapper_1 {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="role_wrapper_1"></div>
<div class="role_wrapper_2">
  <div class="admin2_search">
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <input class="role-search-approval" type="search" placeholder="Enter your keyword">
    </form>
  </div><!-- search_area end  -->
</div>
```

Now, I have a "wrapper_2" area and also have search function.
If I click on item which in "wrapper_2" , the item will add to "wrapper_1".

However, when I input some keyword to search, both of "wrapper_1" and "wrapper_2" will hide the wrong day.

What can I do to only hide the data under div "wrapper_2"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `keyup` function slight modification as below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/m2neqv8g/)**

```
$(".role-search-approval").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
      $(".role_wrapper_2 .roles_approval").each(function() { 
          //Just loop for those items which are in .role_wrapper_2
          if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1) {
              $(this).show();
          } else {
              $(this).hide();    
          }
    });
});
```

> **What was happening?**
>
> You were just adding one element to `wrapper_1` from `wrapper_2` and
>   that element contained all the necessary classes while appending and
>   on your `$.each` even that class was taken count which was appended to
>   `wrapper_1`. So you just need to say which `wrapper's` element you
>   need to filter!! By specifying its parent `element` you can filter
>   those `class` in `$.each`

Comment: $(".role_wrapper_2 > .roles_approval").each(function() (Would go the direct child selector route....)

Comment: Thanks for your help.I knew I need add some specific information for only search under my .roles_approval. just don't know that simple. XD

Comment: Anytime @LateBloomer Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Well, actually there is a bit of a difference between the two though. If he intends on further parenting and at some point has sections of "roles" within wrapper 2 the .roles_approval in .role_wrapper_2 will be selected regardless of whether it is a grandchild great grandchild etc... whereas direct child ".role_wrapper_2 > .roles_approval" will only select direct children.

Comment: @ThatTechGuy True that.. But the case might be vice versa too!! If he want to select all the grand-child, great-grand-child... then this will definitely help but then this is irrelevant here as the OP only asked answer for his current situations and giving answers with imaginations, thinking he might need that, he might need this, might ruin the quality of answer! If he really wants such functionalities, he'll either sort out or come up with one more question! Isn't it..?? :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao That's all well and good absolutely I hear you, I was just referencing the difference since I said "I would go this route" and you said "Yes Exactly" as if it was the same thing, but I just wanted to make sure the difference was clear... :)

Comment: @ThatTechGuy I must agree here that I just overread your comment and did not understood it properly in first instance! My mistake!! :)